# Show that $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb{P}_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Im asked to prove that $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb{P}_{2}$. I know how to show that $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ but i don't know how to do it with polynomials. This is the exercise:

Show that $B = \{1+x,2+x-x^2,1\}$ is a basis of the vector space $\mathbb{P}_{2} =\  $Span$\{1,x,x^2\}$

Comment: It is equivalent to showing that $[1,1,0], [2,1,-1], [1,0,0]$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: What do you mean $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$? $B$ is not even a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ and $a(1+x)+b(2+x-x^2)+c=0$ for all x$ \in \mathbb R$.

If you can show that $a=b=c=0$, then you are done.

Comment: Technically, one also has to show that the the polynomials span $\Bbb P^2$.